# JavaScript Object: How to sort a list of objects that's created using _.groupBy, according to ISO timeStamp?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, underscore.js

I receive a JSON object as a response from the server.

It looks like this.

```
Data = [Object0, Object1, Object2]
```

Each object has values like below.

```
Object0: {carid: 1234, name: "Audi", make: "R8", BookmarkTitle: "Features", Timestamp: "2014-10-09T13:39:15.000-07:00"}
Object1: {carid: 5678, name: "Audi", make: "A4", BookmarkTitle: "Brakes", Timestamp: "2014-10-08T13:39:15.000-07:00"}
Object2: {carid: 1234, name: "Audi", make: "R8", BookmarkTitle: "Features", Timestamp: "2014-10-06T13:39:15.000-07:00"}
```

I wanted to group these by the carid as I wanted to display this in my dropdown. Hence, I used

```
var bookmarkList = _.groupBy(data, function(bookmark){return bookmark.carid});
```

Which returned my list as,

```
{1234: Array[2], 5678: Array[1]}
```

I would like to sort this array in descending order with timestamp as a category.

I tried using `_.sortBy` but didn't work either.

So, if there can be any clarity provided on how to perform sorting at this stage, that would be of great help.

Comment: Do you want to sort the whole list (which is an object, which cannot be sorted), or do you want to sort each `carid`'s array?

Comment: Thanks Bergi, Your question enlightened what I was doing wrong. I was trying to sort an Object which isn't possible, so, I converted that into an array and got it done. Thanks a lot!